# Minimum in rotated sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I am looking at [this leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-minimum-in-rotated-sorted-array/) challenge:

> Suppose an array sorted in ascending order is rotated at some pivot
> unknown to you beforehand.
>
> (i.e.,  `[0,1,2,4,5,6,7]` might become  `[4,5,6,7,0,1,2]`).
>
> Find the minimum element.
>
> You may assume no duplicate exists in the array.

I found this solution [on repl.it](https://repl.it/@Stylebender/Test#index.js):

```
function findMin(nums) {
    if (nums.length === 1) { //Edge
        return nums[0];
    }

    let left = 0, right = nums.length - 1 //Two pointers 

    if (nums[right] > nums[0]) { //Sorted array case
        return nums[0];
    }

    while (left < right) { //Shifted unsorted array 
        const mid = Math.floor((left + right) / 2); 
        if (nums[mid] > nums[right]) left = mid + 1; //If midpoint is larger than last element, look right
        else right = mid; //Else look left 
  }
  return nums[left];
}
```

My question has to do with the logic behind the following line:

```
 if (nums[mid] > nums[right]) left = mid + 1;
```

I've been trying to work out examples on paper, but can someone explain why the above line is the correct logic? Is it because all the smallest elements in a shifted array will always reside on the right side of the array?

Answer (score 0):

You have already checked for a non-shifted sorted array using:

```
if (nums[right] > nums[0]) {                            
    //Sorted array case
        return nums[0];
    }
```

Now let's take an example:

> 3 4 5 2 1

Code:

```
while (left < right) { //Shifted unsorted array 
        const mid = Math.floor((left + right) / 2); 
        
        if (nums[mid] > nums[right]) left = mid + 1; 
        //If midpoint is larger than last element, look right
        
        else right = mid; //Else look left 
  }
```

**Iteration 1:** left = 0 , right = 4  -> mid = 2

Now the left should be mid + 1 as lower values are on the right side. As you are taking the floor, this will not lead to out of index error.

**Iteration 2:** left = 3, right = 4 -> mid = 3

Now the right became mid as nums[mid] <= nums[right].

Thus, returning nums[left] = nums[3] = 1

Answer (score 0):

If you visualise the rotated array, for example [6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5], you have this pattern:

```
            9
         8
      7
   6
                            5
                         4
                      3
                   2
                1

   left         k           right
```

1 is the minimum value to find, and it sits at index *k*. Once you have an index `mid`, there are two possibilities:

- `mid >= k`: we can see that in that case, and only then, `a[mid] <= a[right]`
- `mid < k`: we can see that in that case, and only then, `a[mid] > a[right]`

In the first case all elements that are at the right of `mid` can be ignored, and so we set `right = mid` (the minimum could still be *at* `mid`).

In the second case all elements that are at the left of `mid` can be ignored, including the one at `mid` itself, and so we can set `left = mid + 1`.

And every time that `left` or `right` is adjusted, `k` will remain in that reduced range between `left` and `right`, and so we repeat the same pattern with the same logic.

Comment: Thanks very much. Just wanted to confirm, if the array is rotated does that mean that the right side of the resulting array will always be smaller?

Also, in your example above. After the first pass of the binary search I assume the logic would be to set left = mid since we know that we need to look on the right side of the array?

Comment: Just rotate an array and see what happens. Unless it is completely sorted, the last element of your rotated array would in its normal sort order come right before the first value in the array. Just rotate an array a few times and watch... the logic will come to you when you keep doing this.

Comment: Whether you set `left` or `right` depends on what you find in your `if` condition. That is what I have tried to explain. The code you presented is fine.

Comment: The "drawing" I made should make clear how the right section of the array really belongs *before* the left part if you would have it sorted, so yes, that obviously means those righter values are smaller than the ones in the left section.